# Set size of button with drawable background dynamically/programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, size, drawable

I have a button that has the following properties:

**circle_normal.xml (in res/drawable)**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#FF6347" />

    <size
        android:height="325dp"
        android:width="325dp" />
</shape>
```

**circle.xml (in res/drawable)**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

**activity_main.xml (in res/layout)**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_study"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main.java (in src)**

```
buttonStudy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_study);
```

The final product is that I get a button that is in the shape of a circle. However, due to the difference screen sizes on different Android devices, this one circle size is insufficient. I've looked at a few other questions similar to this but their solutions didn't help me very much. How do I change its size dynamically in the Java code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this way

```
final Button buttonStudy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_study);
buttonStudy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = buttonStudy.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = 100;//change the width size
        params.height= 100;//change the hight size
        buttonStudy.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! :D That's such a simple solution too; I can't believe I couldn't find it elsewhere. Thanks a bunch. (P.S. I edited it a bit to make it more uniform to my own code.)

Answer (score 2):

```
btn = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.button_study);

btn.getLayoutParams().height = x;
btn.getLayoutParams().width = x;

btn.setLayoutParams(btn.getLayoutParams);
```

Using this code, you can set the height and width of the button. Also, this would avoid the parent view  parsing conflict.

Also, you can get the size of screen and then set size of button accordingly:-

For  API<13

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
int screenHeight = display.getHeight(); //not required, just to inform

int x = (int) screenWidth/10; //replace 10 by scaling factor

btn = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.button_study);

btn.getLayoutParams().height = x;
btn.getLayoutParams().width = x;

btn.setLayoutParams(btn.getLayoutParams);
```

For API>=13

```
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int screenWidth = size.x;
int screenHeight = size.y; //not required, just for info

int x = (int) screenWidth/10; //replace 10 by scaling factor
btn = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.button_study);

btn.getLayoutParams().height = x;
btn.getLayoutParams().width = x;

btn.setLayoutParams(btn.getLayoutParams);
```

to check for API level at runtime, use

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {

         //<code> if API>=13 (HONEYCOMB_MR2 is API 13)
}

else {

         //<code> if API<13
}
```

Hope it helps.
Happy Programming :)